# The rebus of jealousy

Tags: visual, rebus

To what quote does this rebus refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> Who's the fairest of them all?

because

> the word who appears to be fainter than the other two (at least on my screen), and that could be interpreted as the other 2 being darker, making 'who' the fairest.

Also, just noticed that

> The jealousy in the title could be alluding to the Snow White story

Comment: This would work better with yellow text, because the original meaning of "fair" is related to blonde hairs.

Comment: @Nzall, I did not realize ... that would have been better indeed